# What kind of graphics manipulation libraries can be used for applying effects / transformation to a small part of an image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, graphics

Looking for programmatic way, and if possible high-level abstract way, to distort / transform  **one or more areas** (if possible, '*non-rectangular*') of an image or pictures (usually JPEGs), for transformations / effects like:

1. Convex bulge / bump
2. Concave depression / sunk (sunk)
3. Localized shrinkage
4. Localized pinch
5. Bullet-hole effect (hole with surrounding areas having some ripple and shrinkage)
6. Overlay image, with some blending

I believe that image manipulation tools can achieve such effects by applying a series of transformations, but I wish to do the above under program control. Not quite sure though, how to achieve this, and what kind of software libraries should I be looking at.

The languages and environment that I'd prefer (simply because I'm relatively more familiar with them) are: C/C++/Java... although I can manage Python, Lua to some extent, on Linux environment.

*Question edited: Nov 1, 2014, to further clarify requirements and context.*

Comment: Why the down-vote ? Especially after I added further clarification, context ! At least leave a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what platform your on or what languages you're familiar with but if you've used Python than PIL or Pillow (a fork of PIL) should be able to do this. Check out [this](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/handbook/tutorial.html) tutorial to see if it would work for you?

Comment: It might be prudent to point out that Pillow is your only option on Python 3.x.

Comment: Thanks Kevin (& furkle). I am not a Pythonista, but I don't mind using Python if it turns out to be the best option in my case. I am a bit more conversant with Java, C/C++. I did check Pillow, and like what I see. However, I am not quite sure how I can apply the effects to small areas of the image (not the whole area) ? Can I work with non-rectangular areas for applying the transformations ? Finally, is there any resource which talks of how to create certain 'effects' using chain of the basic image transformations ?